# What does "poke" mean in "Randomly poke old unanswered questions"?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "poke" mean in below sentence? Please add a source I can refer to.

> Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

Comment: If something is sleeping, and you poke it, it will be roused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we were sitting near each other, and I wanted to get your attention, I might poke your shoulder with my finger.

In the online realm, social media took that word and gave it a virtual meaning, where a "poke" was a gesture meant to attract attention to someone or something.

You asked for a source; at least one dictionary (NOAD) has this use of the word listed:

> **poke** (*verb*) 1 jab or prod (someone or something), esp. with one's finger: *he poked Benny in the ribs and pointed*
>   • (on the social networking site Facebook) attract the attention of (another member of the site) by using the ‘poke’ facility.

So, the advice you quote is recommending that you perform some activity to "poke" your question. If a website lists questions with the most recent activity near the top, "poking" is a way to prevent a question from being buried beneath others.

That said, "every hour or so" seems a bit excessive, and it might draw some ire from the community – but I suppose that depends on the dynamics of the community.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Zii got that from [the description of the Community user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/232555), rather than a suggestion that other users do so. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyD - Thanks for providing additional context. I was puzzled about that :^)

Answer (score 3):

In your example, **poke** is any method which will bring **attention to the unanswered question** so that other users will look at it.

On ell.stackexchange making an edit or adding a comment will bring the question to the top of the queue where other people may interact with it.  This activity would be considered a **poke** in your usage.